# Pull info from a Microsoft Access database into the php and apache web environment?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, microsoft-access

We have a client who uses a custom build client management system that runs on Microsoft access.

The website we have needs to pull some client info from that database. But how do we pull info from a Microsoft Access database into the php and apache web environment?

Is there an odbc connector somewhere that could do the Job?

Comment: Which database are you using on the Web end?  Is this a one time migration or will it be done on a regular basis e.g. daily/weekly/monthly upload?

Answer (score 0):

"Here is how to create an ODBC connection to a MS Access Database"
-- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_db_odbc.asp